# Bring to front a view over foreground image of a frameLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout, background-foreground, bringtofront

I have a frame layout with a foreground image shown below.In my frame layout i have a text view but it is not seen because it stays behind of foreground image.How to take it front over foreground image?

```
<FrameLayout           
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:foreground="@drawable/foreground_image"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/dreams" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="MY TEXT"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would place the image in the FrameLayout as an ImageView, instead of using foreground. Then you can more easily control the order the various things should be drawn.
Foreground will always draw over the content.